# Initializing weights from inception_v3.ckpt in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, I need to load weights from inception_v3 pretrained model in order to use at the following code:

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope, "InceptionV3", [images]) as scope:
            with slim.arg_scope(
                [slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                weights_regularizer=weights_regularizer,
                trainable=False):
                with slim.arg_scope(
                    [slim.conv2d],
                    weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev),
                    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                    normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
                    normalizer_params=batch_norm_params):
                    net, end_points = inception_v3_base(images, scope=scope)
                with tf.variable_scope("logits"):
                    shape = net.get_shape()
                    net = slim.avg_pool2d(net, shape[1:3], padding="VALID", scope="pool")
                    net = slim.dropout(
                            net,
                            keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob,
                            is_training=False,
                            scope="dropout")
                    net = slim.flatten(net, scope="flatten")

    image_embeddings = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
                    inputs=net,
                                num_outputs=512,
                                activation_fn=None,
                                weights_initializer=initializer,
                                biases_initializer=None,
                                scope=scope)
```

How it would be possible to do that? Could you please give a brief example?

There are two weights initializers at the above code. I don't know at which one I have to initialize weights from the model, and how?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have only one `.ckpt` file or do you have more? (e.g., a `.meta` or a `.pbtxt`/`.pb`)

Comment: I have only one .ckpt file, @GPhilo.

Comment: Could you post a link of the page you got the checkpoint from? Is it one of the pretrained models from Tensorflow's model zoo?

Comment: Yes, exactly. "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz"

Comment: Ok, the matching Tensorflow model for that checkpoint is defined in the [python file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v3.py) that goes with the checkpoint. I assume you already downloaded that (if not, do so and put it in the same folder as your script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Read the third point in the list below.

#### Long-ish generic explanation of how to restore a model

Whenever you need to load weights from a checkpoint, you need the matching model definition to be able to define the graph before attempting to restore the weights. This is necessary because **the checkpoint file only contains the values of the variables, it does NOT have information about the structure of the graph itself**.

The model structure can be retrieved in different ways:

- The checkpoint comes with a matching `.meta` file. In this case, import the metagraph and then restore the weights via:

  ```
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-save-dir/my-model-10000.meta')
  new_saver.restore(sess, 'my-save-dir/my-model-10000')
  ```
- The checkpoint comes with a matching `.pb`/`.pbtxt` file containing the serialized `GraphDef`. In this case, load the graph from its definition and then restore the weights:

  - For `.pbtxt`:

    ```
    with open('graph.pbtxt', 'r') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        file_content = f.read()
        text_format.Merge(file_content, graph_def)
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    saver = tf.train.Saver() # note: it is important that this is defined AFTER you import the graph definition or it won't find any variables in the graph to restore
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    ```
  - For `.pb`:

    ```
    with gfile.FastGFile('graph.pb','rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    saver = tf.train.Saver() # note: it is important that this is defined AFTER you import the graph definition or it won't find any variables in the graph to restore
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    ```
- The checkpoint comes with a matching python file containing the model definition. In this case, read through the documentation of the file and find the function that you need to call to define the model. Then, in your script, import the function, call it before defining a `saver` and then restore the variables' values from the checkpoint:

  ```
  from inception_v3 import inception_v3

  logits, endpoints = inception_v3()
  saver = tf.train.Saver() # as above, it is important that this is defined after you define the graph, or it won't find any variables.
  saver.restore(sess, 'inception_v3.ckpt')
  ```

  **Note:** For this case, you need to call the function *exactly* as it was called when the checkpoint was saved (unless you selectively avid to restore some variables), or the restore will fail with an error.

Comment: That is good, but it is not the answer of my question. I want to use this weight as initialization inside the code I have given. I need to get image embeddings.

Comment: But that *is* the answer to your question. Once weights are restored, all the variables are initialised to the values taken from the checkpoint. After that, you can do whatever you need with them. Just `sess.run` the tensor whose value you want to compute after restoring the weights and you'll have your embedding